# How does c allow you to not pass all the parameters?

Tags: c, parameters, parameter-passing

So I never realized this until I accidentally did it. The following is a method header i have:

```
void processI_TypeInstruction(char *I_TypeInstruction, char* currentLine,
        FILE *outputFilePointer, VariableVector *labelVector);
```

one of my calls to this method looks like this:

```
processI_TypeInstruction("lw", line1, outputFile);
```

and all my tests pass and everything works. I was wondering what C does to make this functionality work??? Thanks.

Comment: hate being pedantic, but isn't it a bit silly to say methods in C?

Comment: Are you sure it is C and not C++?

Comment: Is there any way to check in eclipse?

Comment: I don't know. Try to declare a class and see if it compiles. `class foobar {}`

Comment: Because unlike C, C++ supports features like default parameter values and function overloading, it means you can have many functions with the same name as long as they accept different parameters, or parameters that will assume a default value if you ommit them.

Comment: @Chingy Can't you just search for multiple function definitions for `processI_TypeInstruction`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must not have the header file with the [prototype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype#Uses) for `processI_TypeInstruction` in the file with that call.

Function prototypes are not required in C.  If a function does not have a prototype, the compiler makes no assumption about the number of parameters so it will allow you to pass any number of parameters in a function call.  The is the behavior of the original language.  Function prototypes were not added until the 1989 C standard.

The call works because the [C calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl) has the caller clean up the stack.  Since the caller knows how many parameters were passed, it can clean up all the parameters that it passed.  Of course if the function tries to access a parameter then it will read into un-initialized stack space and who knows what will happen.

Comment: But the compiler would still need to know "what function he is talking about" when deciding what address it will make the `call`, so to compile sucessfully at some point it will have to connect the dots, and when it does I don't think it will ignore the function declaration. Altrough I know what you said about the stack is correct, I don't see how the compiler can do its job while "accidentally" allowing that to happen at the same time.

Comment: @Havenard - no the compiler doesn't need to know that.  C compiles each file as an independent unit. If the function it implemented another file the compiler knows nothing about the other function.  All it does is store the name of the function and lets the linker hook the call up and the linker has no information about what parameters a function takes it just has a name.

Answer (score 1):

That should definitely be a compilation error in C, however, C++ does support function overloading (same function name, different number of arguments, different function signature)...

Comment: C does not support overloading.